# 7 segment display basys3 how to use 2 digit?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I know a little bit of VHDL.

My goal is to have a 4 bit vector input and sending an output to a 7 segment display at base4 number.

e.g. 1111->33,  1001->21

I am struggling with the conversion from base2 to base4 numbers in VHDL. As previously stated, when I have converted base2 to base4 I want to send it to a 7 segment display, please could you advise me how to do this?

Comment: Binary is easy to convert to any power-of-to-based number system. Just group bits by bigger base/2. In case of base 4 group them by 4/2=2: 00->0, 01->1, 10->2,11->3. 1110->32

Comment: I know how to convert in real life but how can i do this in VHDL

Comment: Do you know how to dissect a vector in VHDL? Use that. Split vector of length l to l/2 vectors of lengths 2.

Comment: @fukanchik actually no i dont know how to dissect and how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

Binary is easy to convert to any power-of-2-based number system like 4 or 8 or 16. Just group bits by `log2(bigger base)`. In case of base 4 group them by `log2(4)=2`:

```
00->0
01->1
10->2
11->3
1110->32
```

You simply split vector of length `X` to `X/2` vectors of lengths `2` each by connecting wires:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

-- 8 binary bit number to 4 base4 numbers
-- binary - is input number
-- d1 is the most significant base-4 digit
-- ...
-- d4 is the least significant base-4 digit

entity BinToBase4 is
port(binary : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
     d1 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
     d2 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
     d3 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
     d4 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0)
    );
end BinTobase4;

architecture rtl of BinToBase4 is
begin
    d1 <= binary(7 downto 6);
    d2 <= binary(5 downto 4);
    d3 <= binary(3 downto 2);
    d4 <= binary(1 downto 0);
end rtl;
```

Testbench for this:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity testbench is
end testbench; 

architecture tb of testbench is
component BinToBase4 is
port(
    binary : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
    d1 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
    d2 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
    d3 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
    d4 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0)
);
end component;

    signal num : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal d1 : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    signal d2 : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    signal d3 : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    signal d4 : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
begin
    b4: BinToBase4 port map(num,d1,d2,d3,d4);
     process
    begin
      num <= "10110001";
      wait for 1 ns;

      assert(d1="10") report "Fail 10" severity error;
      assert(d2="11") report "Fail 11" severity error;
      assert(d3="00") report "Fail 00" severity error;
      assert(d4="01") report "Fail 01" severity error;
      wait;
    end process;
end tb;
```

You may want to extend `d1`, `d2`, `d3`, `d4`  to four bits to connect them directly to 7-segment display. Use concatenation `&`:

```
d1 <= "00" & binary(7 downto 6);
d2 <= "00" & binary(5 downto 4);
d3 <= "00" & binary(3 downto 2);
d4 <= "00" & binary(1 downto 0);
```

just don't forget to adjust vector sizes accordingly.

I.e. dx would become...

```
signal dx : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
```